# Combining 2 codes in Python

Tags: python

I have generated these two codes.

The first generates a country according to the probability given by the number of customers in each country:

```
import random
selectp = random.choices(
        population=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    weights=[0.2307, 0.0769, 0.3846, 0.1923, 0.1153],
    k=1
)
print(selectp)
```

And the second generates a random number of 4 characters by filling in the numbers on the left with zero where appropriate:

```
import random
num = random.randrange(1, 9999)
# using string's zfill
num_with_zeros = str(num).zfill(4)
print (num_with_zeros)
```

What I need to do is to combine these codes to generate a result of the following type, for example, in a random way:

```
A-0213, B-2345, A-0001...
```

The added complication is that for each letter there are a limited number of combinations, which are:

- For A, the numbers will go from A-0000 to A-0300
- For B, the numbers will go from B-0000 to B-0100
- For C, the numbers will go from C-0000 to C-0500
- For D, the numbers will go from D-0000 to D-0250
- For E, the numbers will go from E-0000 to E-0150

Any idea how to do it?

---

Edit:

So what I need is a code that randomly generates a combination of the type:

A-0001, B-0035...

keeping in mind that the probability distribution for the letters is:

- A = 0.2307
- B = 0.0769
- C = 0.3846
- D = 0.1923
- E = 0.1153

And that the number must be between the following numbers:

- For A, the numbers will go from A-0000 to A-0300
- For B, the numbers will go from B-0000 to B-0100
- For C, the numbers will go from C-0000 to C-0500
- For D, the numbers will go from D-0000 to D-0250
- For E, the numbers will go from E-0000 to E-0150

Comment: Neither of those are functions

Comment: You don't have *any* functions. Read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions.

Comment: Rather than thinking of this as "combining these two codes", you ned to start from scratch and describe the problem you are trying to solve. Write in words exactly what you want to do. So for example, you could do something like 1. Randomly choose a letter from A-E. (You need to specify the distribution. Is it uniform? Or something else.) 2. Randomly choose a number. (How do you determine the range the number is chosen from? Again, is it a uniform distribution?) 3. Concatenate the two together.

Comment: So what I need is a code that randomly generates a combination of the type:

A-0001, B-0035...

keeping in mind that the probability distribution for the letters is:

A = 0.2307
B = 0.0769
C = 0.3846
D = 0.1923
E = 0.1153
And that the number must be between the following numbers:

For A, the numbers will go from A-0000 to A-0300
For B, the numbers will go from B-0000 to B-0100
For C, the numbers will go from C-0000 to C-0500
For D, the numbers will go from D-0000 to D-0250
For E, the numbers will go from E-0000 to E-0150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a dictionary to store what the allowed numbers are, and then you can simply add to strings with `+`

```
import random

max_vals = {"A": 300, "B": 100, "C": 500, "D": 250, "E": 150}

def random_code():
    letter = random.choices(list(max_vals.keys()),
                            weights=[0.2307, 0.0769, 0.3846, 0.1923, 0.1153],
    k=1)[0]
    num = random.randrange(0, max_vals[letter]) # You allow 0000 in the examples in the question
    # using string's zfill
    num_with_zeros = str(num).zfill(4)
    return letter + "-" + num_with_zeros

for _ in range(10):
    print(random_code())
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

def rand_letter_code():
    letters = {
        "A": {"prob": 0.3207, "range": 300},
        "B": {"prob": 0.0769, "range": 100},
        "C": {"prob": 0.3846, "range": 500},
        "D": {"prob": 0.1923, "range": 250},
        "E": {"prob": 0.1153, "range": 150},
    }

    letter = random.choices(
        population=list(letters.keys()),
        weights=[values["prob"] for values in letters.values()],
    )[0]

    num = str(random.randrange(0, letters[letter]["range"])).zfill(4)

    return f"{letter}-{num}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the 4 digit code dependent on the country? If so, then you could have something like this:

```
def get_code(country):
     if country is A:
         create random num in range
     elif country is B:
         ...
     ...
     ...

# country code picker here
code = get_code(country)
output = str(country) + "-" + str(code)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a dictionary to map the endpoints.

```
import random

ranges = {
    'A': 300,
    'B': 100,
    'C': 500,
    'D': 250,
    'E': 150
}

selectp = random.choices(
        population=list(ranges.keys()),
    weights=[0.2307, 0.0769, 0.3846, 0.1923, 0.1153],
    k=1
)

end = ranges[selectp[0]]
num = random.randrange(0, end)
# using string's zfill
num_with_zeros = str(num).zfill(4)

print('%s-%s' % (selectp[0], num_with_zeros))
```